# When I load an image in background, it works fine, crashes when I load it into an ImageView inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to load images in the background to populate the images in a ListView.
If I load an image in the background and load it into an image that is not in the ListView it works fine.  When I try to load the bitmap in an ImageView that is in the ListView it crashes.

This is what I do:

1. Created a Subclass of the AsyncTask
2. Overide the GetView in Iconic adpter.
3. In `getView()`, get the ImageView to load the image into by 
   `(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon)`, where icon is a id in the xml file for the ListView
4. start the background process by 
   `new MyBackground( (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon) ).execute()`
   it crashes when it tries to load the bitmap into `(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon)`
   Now if I try to load the background image into an ImageView that is not in the List it works fine, i.e `MyBackground( (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.MyImage) ).execute()`

Code:

```
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    Activity context;

    IconicAdapter(Activity context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, LinkName);


        this.context=context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                            ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        TextView label=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.label);
        label.setText( LinkName.get(position));
        ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);

        //new MyBackground( (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon) ).execute();
    //  new MyBackground( (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimage) ).execute();

        return(row);
    }
}

class MyBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>
{
    int p1;
    String p2;
    ImageView myimage;
//  @Override 
    public MyBackground(ImageView in )
    {
    //  super.MyBackground
        myimage=in;
    }


    @Override
       protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         try {
           String uri = "http://www.besttechsolutions.biz/icon.png";
           HttpGet request = new HttpGet(uri);
           HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
           return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(response.getEntity().getContent());
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return null;
       }

    @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {
         if(image == null){
             Log.d("ted", "could not download image");
//           Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Download failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         else{
             // losd into ListView
            // this will crash if image is in the list vue
           myimage.setImageBitmap(image);
         }
       }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar a few months ago. ListViews seem to destroy child views if they're not on-screen, so it may well be that the ImageView you're trying to update has been destroyed when the background thread completes.

A stack trace would be useful, to see exactly where things are falling over - 'crashes' can cover a multitude of sins.